# Is there a way to skip errors in procedures and resuming procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, mysql-5, foreign-key

When there is a unique key in a table (not `PRIMARY KEY`) and procedure is running, on duplicate key error the whole process will be halted. I want to resume on error and call the procedure again.

The procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `injatest`.`LoadData` ()
BEGIN

    DECLARE x INT;

    SET x = 1;
    WHILE x <= 14400 DO
        INSERT INTO junc_question_course_iq(q_id,iq_id,ct_id) VALUES
        (CEIL(RAND()*1000), CEIL(RAND()*48), CEIL(RAND()*10));
        SET x = x + 1;
    END WHILE;

END $$


DELIMITER ;
```

I want to insert about 14000 records in a junction table, but the problem arise when there is a duplicate key for unique(iq_id,q_id)? what do do?

Comment: Which DBMS is this?

Comment: MySQL with InnoDB SE

Comment: Can't you use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` ?

Comment: Or `INSERT IGNORE`

Comment: See this answer for differences: [“INSERT IGNORE” vs “INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE` to ignore the key violation by declaring an empty block as an exception handler, as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `injatest`.`LoadData` ()
BEGIN

    DECLARE x INT;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000' BEGIN END;
    SET x = 1;
    WHILE x <= 14400 DO
        INSERT INTO junc_question_course_iq(q_id,iq_id,ct_id) VALUES
        (CEIL(RAND()*1000), CEIL(RAND()*48), CEIL(RAND()*10));
        SET x = x + 1;
    END WHILE;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was looking for a no-op keyword.  I didn't even consider an empty code block!